# querySelectorAll with two or more dataset as queries

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have a table i created lets call it RPT_ACCOUNTS

CODE|DESCRIPTION|TYPE
01|BANK|BA
02|TAX|TA

When I pull the information from the datatable i create the table visually in html

```
row.dataset.rpt_accounts_code= DBRow.CODE;
row.dataset.rpt_accounts_description= DBRow.DESCRIPTION;
row.dataset.rpt_accounts_type= DBRow.TYPE;
```

So now I have the 3 datasets.

now I want to filter so i can run through a for loop. (this is my problem)

if i use

```
var ROWS= RPT_ACCOUNTS.querySelectorAll('tr[data-rpt_accounts_code="' + searchvalue + '"]');
```

IT WORKS!

But now i need two search values

so i read up and saw it is supported with a "," but it doesn't work. i have tried many combinations

```
var ROWS= RPT_ACCOUNTS.querySelectorAll('tr[data-rpt_accounts_code="' + searchvalue + '"],tr[data-rpt_accounts_type="' + searchvalue2 + '"]');

var ROWS= RPT_ACCOUNTS.querySelectorAll('tr[data-rpt_accounts_code="' + searchvalue + '"],[data-rpt_accounts_type="' + searchvalue2 + '"]');

var ROWS= RPT_ACCOUNTS.querySelectorAll('tr[data-rpt_accounts_code="' + searchvalue + '"]','tr[data-rpt_accounts_type="' + searchvalue2 + '"]');
```

anyone one of the above methods go through, but it pulls all the data not just the line I'm looking for.

Any help would be awesome.

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/custardcs/q8a6uysg/5/

Comment: Make sure your "searchvalue2" does not invalidate your query. Sincerely, I don't see any other reason on why this should not work. Sounds very strange!

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright ill do that now and update it give me a few.

Comment: @guest271314 updated with stacksnippet

Comment: The expected result is returned at linked jsfiddle

Comment: @guest271314 what linked jsfiddle? sorry im very confused.

Comment: The jsfiddle linked at Question. Where `<button>` having text `"build table"` is clicked first, then `<button>` having text `"query table"` is clicked `.querySelectorAll()` returns multiple `tr` elements at `QRYFUN()` call

Comment: @guest271314 that isnt correct. I am asking it for everything where rpt_account_code = 'TA3' and everything where TYPE = 'ZZ'

Comment: No, the selector is `'tr[data-rpt_account_code="TA3"],tr[data-rpt_account_type="TA"]'`. Where is `"ZZ"` within selector? If you include `console.log(ROWS4L);` following `.querySelectorAll()` call you should be able to view the result. Ah, you are trying to select element having multiple `data-*` attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query multiple attributes, express them like `el[propA=val][propB=val]`, so, in your case

```
var ROWS= RPT_ACCOUNTS.querySelectorAll('tr[data-rpt_accounts_code="' + searchvalue + '"][data-rpt_accounts_type="' + searchvalue2 + '"]')
```